# select pages with condition on page title using rest api

Tags: 2013, rest

I am using rest api to filter pages and fetch their title and url

```
//_api/search/query?querytext='Path:http:sharepointpath owstaxIdTaxKeyword:81394a-cedb-4c19
AND 
Title<>sometitle'&rowlimit=5& selectproperties='Title'&enablequeryrules=false
```

Its fetching from the paths that I specify, but the problem is I want to select pages that do not have title that I give ( `Title<>sometitle` ). But the query is still returning results with title **sometitle**
What have I missed?

Comment: Have you tried `NOT Title="sometitle"` ?

Comment: Thanks NOT Title:sometitle worked
Can you post this as answer if its okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this syntax instead:

`NOT Title="sometitle"`

So your query becomes

```
//_api/search/query?querytext='Path:http:sharepointpath owstaxIdTaxKeyword:81394a-cedb-4c19
AND NOT Title="sometitle"'&rowlimit=5& selectproperties='Title'&enablequeryrules=false
```